# Populating winform ListView from Calling External Class, not adding image and text

Tags: c#, winforms, external, imagelist

I am trying to add a new image list with text describing each image below each image. I have set the listview to large icons and tried many other attempts to get preview images back into the first form.
I have been able to either
1. get very small images into the list view
2. get just the text into the listview
3. get the very tiny images again with text first then the images, not together.

I have tried all the overloaded methods and I am still at a loss as to why i can't even get a Properties.resources.image in as an image placeholder. except as a tiny image. And yes I have set the listview large icon mode and tried the imageSize properties, nothing works. Also some attempts usually with a technique that appears like it is following an explanation on here fails to show anything in the listview on the frstForm.
Any hints would be appreciated.

```
  public ImageList imageList_c = new ImageList();

    private Family_Loader_ExtEventDialog _frstForm;


               foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Bitmap> kvp in element_Dict(_doc_new, BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls))
                {
                    //imageList_c.ImageSize = new Size(120, 120);
                    //imageList_c.Images.Add(kvp.Key, Properties.Resources.folder);
                    _frstForm.listView_Family.Items.Add(kvp.Key);
                }
```

//_frstForm.listView_Family.LargeImageList = imageList_c;

Comment: The icon size is a system setting.  Consider that you simply picked the wrong View, you have control over the size when you pick View = Tile instead.  The TileSize property then sets the size.  Mysterious question title btw.

Comment: I found the soln, thanx for giving me some hope Passant! The below code after adding the images to an imagelist dictionary helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
           imageList_c.Images.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

           _frstForm.listView_Family.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.LargeIcon;
            _frstForm.listView_Family.LargeImageList = imageList_c;    
            for (int i = 0; i < imageList_c.Images.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.ImageIndex = i;
                item.Text = imageList_c.Images.Keys[i];
                _frstForm.listView_Family.Items.Add(item);
            }
```